# I'm trying to create a slider using one image. How do I reset the position?

Tags: jquery, slider

I am new to jQuery, and messing around with an image slider. Although I know there's lots out there. I'd rather understand it myself.

Here's what I have, and pardon the newbie stuff.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      // image timer
        setInterval("slideImages()", 2000);
    });

    function slideImages(){
        //sets current position or slider
        var currentPosition = 0;
        $(".main-img").animate({'marginLeft': '-=960px'});
         currentPosition++

        if(currentPosition > 3){
            alert("done");
        }
    }

    slideImages();
```

Easy to make work, but I can't seem to sort out the logic to have it come back to it's start point.

Can I increment a counter for its position every time it animates?

Answer (score 0):

in this statement

```
if(currentPosition > 3)
{
        alert("done");
}
```

you have finished so reset everything

```
if(currentPosition > 3)
{
        alert("done");
        currentPosition = 0;
        reset the image here
}
```

if you want it to gracefully slide back then do something like this

```
  if(currentPosition > 3)
  {
        while (currentPosition>0)
        {
              $(".main-img").animate({'marginLeft': '+=960px'});
              currentPosition--;
        }
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. currentPosition doesn't increment, so I think I have it in the wrong place. I'll keep messing around! Thanks!

Comment: on your code you have no ; after currentposition++  should be currentPosition++;

Comment: Yeah I caught that, but I can't seem to sort it. I just need it to increment every time the animation runs.

Comment: you will also need to put the animation in a while loop in order to increment the position, pseudo - while image-pos != FinPos{ animate and increment }

Comment: Ok, I will give this a shot! Thanks again.

Comment: no probs if it works dont forget to accept the answer